# How to determine pressure in a syringe / Rüchardt's experiment?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am currently working as a theorist on Rüchardt's experiment for a university project and cannot figure out how to get the pressure inside the syringe and how it might vary for different volumes of gas. The two ways I can think of are either to assume that the pressure in the syringe is equal to the combined atmospheric pressure and pressure due to the plunger (in which case the pressure is volume independent) or to use the ideal gas law (in which case the pressure is volume dependent). How do I know which one to use as they give contradicting statements?

Comment: Where does  the syringe come in? The experiment is usually done, as we did it in high school,  with a ball bouncing in a tube.

Comment: Our experiment is slightly different - it uses a gas syringe which is then depressed by a few mm and undergoes damped oscillations

Comment: Ah, but then how can  the pressure be  "volume independent"  in any case? The force accelerating  the piston is its weight, the $PV^\gamma=const$ determined pressure $P$  exerted by the trapped gas and the constant external atmospheric pressure.

Comment: But surely if we're taking P = P_atm + mg/A, this is volume independent, no?

Comment: When the plunger bouncing its eq of motion  is  surely $m a_z =- mg +A(P_{inside}-P_{atmosphere})$  where $A$ = area and $P_{inside}$ is *not* constant, but is determined from $ P_{inside}V^\gamma=constant$. Perhaps you should show a figure?